# MySQL while executing hierarchy query i.e. parent to child relationship, getting wrong output

Tags: mysql

In MySQL while executing below hierarchy query i.e. parent to child relationship

```
SELECT account_id
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      account_id,
      CASE WHEN account_id = 100016
        THEN @idlist := CONCAT(account_id)
      WHEN FIND_IN_SET(parent_id, @idlist)
        THEN @idlist := CONCAT(@idlist, ',', account_id) END AS checkId
    FROM account_master
    ORDER BY account_id ASC
  ) AS T
WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL;
```

Getting different output while in second time execution it get's proper output.

Can any one please tell me what's the solution apply for above written query to get proper output in first execution.

Comment: This is quite messy. I assume you have some of your parent ids have a lower account number than your account `100016`. Assume account `100016` is the parent for account `1`. You order by account number. So when you run your query, `@idlist` is empty when it reaches account `1` (so condition is false). When it reaches `100016`, `@idlist` will be set. For the second run, your variable `@idlist` already contains the values, e.g. at least account `10016`. So when it starts at account `1`, the condition is now true, it will get added. But only by chance. It will not be correct in every situation.

Comment: Add some sample data (with table create statements and insert statements, so anyone can just copy&paste it and try it out) and what you are trying to get as a result, because from your code it is not clear what you are trying to acchieve. Or checkout any of the tree related questions on the right side under "related", you might already find your answer there.

Comment: Thanks for sharing information.

I want to get parent to child data, but while executing query in first attempt getting different o/p while in second time it's getting proper output.

Please help me to get it fixed.

Comment: Below is my table creation query as well as data insertion..

CREATE TABLE account_master ( account_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  parent_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
) ;
INSERT INTO account_master VALUES (999999,'PARENT',0),(100001,'CHILD_1',999999),(100002,'CHILD_2',999999),(100016,'CHILD_3',999999)
,(200001,'S_CHILD_1',100002),(200002,'S_CHILD_2',100002),(200003,'S_CHILD_3',100016),(400001,'S_S_CHILD_1',200001),(400002,'S_S_CHILD_2',200002),(400003,'S_S_CHILD_3',200003);

Comment: a) edit your question and add the code there, not in a comment. You will even get a bronze badge for it :-) b) You cannot get the tree your way, you need a completely new code/idea/way. As I said, on the right side under "related" are a lot of questions (and answers) that do exactly as you want. To give you one more link: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). It describes two methods to get a tree, one with your data structure, one with a more database friendly structure called "nested tree".